# Trying to get a functon to detect when a certain number or lowercase or Uppercase letter is detected in a input tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I recently got off a coding block that I have had for over half a year and to put it a long story short im trying to make a project that detects when a number or letter is detected .

I have been stuck at this error for the past 4 hours

The HTML

```
<form  class="form1 "action="">
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="b" > 
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="buttonlog"   onclick="WriteWorker()">console input</button>
```

The JavaScript

```
var answers = document.getElementById('fname').value;
var button1 = document.getElementById('buttonlog');


function WriteWorker(CapitalLetters, LowerLetters, NumberLetters, button1 , answers ) {
    
    if (CapitalLetters >= answers) {
         return console.log('It is a capital letter') 
    } else if ( answers >= LowerLetters) {
       return  console.log('It is a lower letter') 
    } else if ( answers >= NumberLetters) {
      return console.log('It is a number')
    } else ( answers = answers ) 
      return  console.log('something is wrong')
};
```

and example of my javascript array

```
var CapitalLetters = {
    "A" : [
     "M24,36 L24,20 L13,3 L3,20 L3,36  v-10 h20 z",
    ],
    "B" : [
     "M20,36 v-36 h18 a5,5 0 0 1 5,18 h-25 h25  a5,5 0 0 1 5,18 z  ",
    ],
    "C" : [
     "M0,20 a5,5 0 0 1 10,45 h-10 ",
    ],
```

I thank you for your time

Comment: "project that detects when a number or letter is detected" -- sorry, I'm not clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: Well to be more specifc I am planning on writing a program where when letters are typed  after you hit the button . 

It will write the letters like how you write them on a piece of paper.  Mainly since  the average mans penmanship is bad and I need projects. 

The code you see on the capital A B and C is the sequence of writing those letters